# Connecting to ClojureScript bREPL: clojure.browser.repl/connect throws TypeError in compiled JavaScript

Tags: clojure, google-closure-compiler, leiningen, google-closure, clojurescript

I'm trying to connect to a ClojureScript browser REPL, and I'm having trouble with `clojure.browser.repl/connect`. My compiled JavaScript throws a `TypeError` trying to call `appendChild` on a `null` object in the block of Google Closure code at the top. I'm following the instructions in *[ClojureScript: Up and Running](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920025139.do)* (Chapter 9, p.78, available in the preview), and wondering if the tooling for this has changed since it was published.

I'm using Leiningen 2.0.0, Java 1.6.0_37, OS X 10.7.5, plus the dependencies in my `project.clj`:

```
(defproject brepl-hello "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
                 [org.clojure/clojurescript "0.0-1552"]
                 [compojure "1.1.5"]
                 [ring/ring-jetty-adapter "1.1.8"]]
  :plugins [[lein-cljsbuild "0.3.0"]]
  :source-paths ["src/clj"]
  :cljsbuild {:builds [{
                :source-paths ["src/cljs"]
                :compiler {
                 :output-to "resources/public/brepl-hello.js"
                 :optimizations :whitespace 
                 :pretty-print true}}]})
```

Here's the only ClojureScript source file, `src/cljs/brepl_hello/brepl-hello.cljs`:

```
(ns brepl-hello
  (:require [clojure.browser.repl :as repl]))

(repl/connect "http://localhost:9000/repl")
```

This compiles to the file `resources/public/brepl-hello.js`, which I've inserted into `index.html` in the same directory:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="brepl-hello.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```

I've been serving this on port 3000 with Ring/Jetty from the REPL or Python SimpleHTTPServer. When I open this page in Chrome, the dev console shows `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'appendChild' of null`, with a traceback to this `if`/`else` block in the Google Closure code at the top of the complied js file, where `parentElm` (passed in to the containing function as a parameter) is `null`.

```
if(goog.userAgent.GECKO || goog.userAgent.WEBKIT) {
    window.setTimeout(goog.bind(function() {
      parentElm.appendChild(iframeElm);
      iframeElm.src = peerUri.toString();
      goog.net.xpc.logger.info("peer iframe created (" + iframeId + ")")
    }, this), 1)
  }else {
    iframeElm.src = peerUri.toString();
    parentElm.appendChild(iframeElm);
    goog.net.xpc.logger.info("peer iframe created (" + iframeId + ")")
  }
```

This seems to be a problem with `clojure.browser.repl/connect`. Swapping out this line in the ClojureScript source for something like:

```
(ns brepl-hello
  (:require [clojure.browser.repl :as repl]))

(.write js/document "Hello World!")
```

Will compile and run in the browser just fine. I suspect something is misconfigured in my build settings or directory structure, or I'm making a noob mistake somewhere in all this. What's changed since the time the instructions I'm following were published? I found a couple references to this problem in the #clojure irc logs, but no solution.

Finally, here's an abbreviated directory tree for reference:

```
├── out
│   ├── cljs
│   │   ├── core.cljs
│   │   └── core.js
│   ├── clojure
│   │   └── browser
│   │       ├── event.cljs
│   │       ├── event.js
│   │       ├── net.cljs
│   │       ├── net.js
│   │       ├── repl.cljs
│   │       └── repl.js
│   └── goog
│       └── [...] 
├── pom.xml
├── project.clj
├── resources
│   └── public
│       ├── brepl-hello.js
│       └── index.html
├── src
│   ├── clj
│   │   └── brepl_hello
│   │       └── core.clj
│   └── cljs
│       └── brepl_hello
│           └── brepl-hello.cljs
└─── target
     ├── brepl-hello-0.1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
     ├── classes
     ├── cljsbuild-compiler-0
     │   ├── brepl_hello
     │   │   └── brepl-hello.js
     │   ├── cljs
     │   │   ├── core.cljs
     │   │   └── core.js
     │   └── clojure
     │       └── browser
     │           ├── event.cljs
     │           ├── event.js
     │           ├── net.cljs
     │           ├── net.js
     │           ├── repl.cljs
     │           └── repl.js
     └── stale
         └── extract-native.dependencies
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, its open source and looking at the code it seems that `document.body` is null at the time the repl hidden iframe is being added to it (the `connect` call leads to this point).

You should do this `connect` call on dom ready or body on load and it should work fine.

Comment: You're right! This is a plain old uninitialized element. Oops.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at:

https://github.com/magomimmo/modern-cljs/blob/master/doc/tutorial-02.md

or, for a better brepl experience, here

https://github.com/magomimmo/modern-cljs/blob/master/doc/tutorial-18.md

Comment: Great resources, thank you for putting them together